# I can't get access to the file or 'READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' by Karumi Dexter. It is working till Sdk-32 properly but it's not working on 33

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

Function for choosing video .

private void ChooseVideo(){

```
    Dexter.withContext(this)
            .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new PermissionListener() {

                @Override public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(  );
                    //new line added
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    intent.setType( "video/*" );

                    intent.setAction( Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT );
                    startActivityForResult( intent,102 );
                }
                @Override public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {

                }
                @Override public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                   token.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            }).check();

}
```

//on activity result

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult( requestCode, resultCode, data );
    if (requestCode==102 &resultCode==RESULT_OK);
    videoUri=data.getData();
    binding.VideoViewAVA.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    binding.VideoViewAVA.setVideoURI(videoUri);

    Cursor mCursor =  getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query( videoUri,null,null,null,null );
    int indexedName =mCursor.getColumnIndex( OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME );
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    songName = mCursor.getString(indexedName);
    finalSongTitle = songName.replace(".mp4","")
                            .replace(".wmv","")
                            .replace(".webm","")
                            .replace(".mkv"," ");
    mCursor.close();

    binding.btnUploadVideo.setEnabled(true);
    binding.vTitle.setText(finalSongTitle);

}
```

[Output should be look Like This]
**But it's not working properly.**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAsZu.png)

Answer (score 0):

> I can't get access to the file or 'READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' by Karumi Dexter. It is working till Sdk-32 but it's not working on the 33.

As it is mentioned on the official page, the [Dexter library](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter):

> Is no longer under active development.

And this has been happening for 2 years now. So it can work with Sdk-32 but not with Sdk-33 because it isn't maintained anymore. My recommendation in such cases would be to use your own logic regarding permission as it is mentioned in the [official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE). Please also see that there is a note there regarding the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` that says:

> **Starting in API level 33, this permission has no effect.** If your app accesses other apps' media files, request one or more of these permissions instead: [READ_MEDIA_IMAGES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_MEDIA_IMAGES), [READ_MEDIA_VIDEO](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_MEDIA_VIDEO), [READ_MEDIA_AUDIO](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_MEDIA_AUDIO). Learn more about the [storage permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#storage-permission) that are associated with media files.

So most likely that's the reason why you get that behavior.

Comment: Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Answer (score 0):

For using `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` you have never needed permission `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

For no Android version.

So remove the check and just launch the intent.